# parse text file name with jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I need to get the name of the file which actually begins with something like 45-**something**.log. I could grab 45, but not the rest since **something** consists of random numbers. Moreover, such this file is already on server and I need to look for it beforehand.

I already tried something like following:

```
       <%
        String line ="";

        String file = "/tmp/smsrouter/" + pageContext.getAttribute("cid");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int count = 0;
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            String[] parts = line.split("\\,");

            lineNumber++;
            if(parts[3].equals("0") && count < lineNumber)
            {
                    count++;
            }
       }
       count = (count/lineNumber)*100;
       br.close();

      %>
```

obviously, it won't get any result as expected. What should I do then?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The name that you need to grab is inside the file as text or is what you trying to get with `pageContext.getAttribute("cid")`. BTW you should use jsp's only for display data (views). It's better to separate the concerns an put your logic in a Servlet.

Comment: @SérgioMichels: cid is already inside the file as result of database query. So the thing is, I have plenty of files on certain directory so-called /tmp/smsrouter. I, therefore, would like to search the appropriate file according to prefix cid-something.log then I will do the rest with the respective file.

Comment: You have more than one file with the same cid? Can you just use the [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))?

Comment: @SérgioMichels  :the file is unique according to cid. So, there will be only one file for each cid.

Comment: Why not iterator /tmp/smsrouter/ dir and match file name you want?

Comment: @a.k.aMark: Could you please give code snippet?

Comment: @DoniAndriCahyono: Code in the question read lines from File no fileName. Its unrelated.

Comment: @HardikMishra: Ok, it's my mistake. I just did copy-paste from my current work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not iterator /tmp/smsrouter/ dir and match file name you want?

```
    File[] files = new File("/tmp/smsrouter/").listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()||!file.getName().startsWith("45-")) {
            continue;
        } else {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            int count = 0;
            int lineNumber = 0;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                String[] parts = line.split("\\,");

                lineNumber++;
                if(parts[3].equals("0") && count < lineNumber)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            count = (count/lineNumber)*100;
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

probably you want extract the count logic to another method. Hope this help.

This is not suggested in real production system , as the invoking maybe very long that request timeout maybe raised.